# Repeater Inside ModalPopup extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I am having a repeater to be displayed inside a modal popup extender,I am able to bind the values and everything works fine,but when the popup is showing up,it doesn't show the repeater.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="dummy" runat="server">
</div>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="mpeOIR" TargetControlID="dummy"
   PopupControlID="pnlOIR_View" DropShadow="true" CancelControlID="btn_modal_cancel" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlOIR_View" runat="server" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" Height="600px" Width="600px"
   Style="display: none">
   <div class="titl-bg" style="width: 580px;">
      <div class="cont-title" style="width: 580px;">
         LIST OF OIR CREATED
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="RPT">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <asp:Repeater ID="rptr_OIR_view"  runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptr_OIR_ItemCommand"
            OnItemDataBound="rptr_OIR_ItemDatabound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
               <tr>
                  <th>
                     OIR NO
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     INCIDENT DATE
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     EMPLOYEE NAME
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     AGE
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     DEPARTMENT NAME
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     INJURY LOCATION
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     VIEW
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <%# Eval("OIR_NO")%>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <%# Eval("INCIDENT_DATE")%>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <%# Eval("FIRSTNAME")%>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <%# Eval("DEPARTMENTNAME")%>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <%# Eval("LOCATIONNAME")%>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_OIR_view" runat="server" CommandName="view" CausesValidation="false"
                        ImageUrl="~/Images/download_arrow.png" Width="20px" Height="20px" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OIR_NO")%>' />
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
      </table>
   </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

And here is what i have done to show the popup:

```
protected void ReporterCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (EHSIMSDataContext db = new EHSIMSDataContext())
    {
        var _OIR_view = (from oir in db.OCCUPATIONAL_INJURY_REPORTs
                         join e in db.EMPLOYEEs on oir.EMPLOYEE_ID equals e.EMPLOYEE_ID
                         join d in db.DEPARTMENTs on oir.DEPARTMENT_ID equals d.DEPARTMENT_ID
                         join l in db.LOCATIONs on oir.INJURY_LOCATION_ID equals l.LOCATION_ID
                         select new
                         {
                                      oir.OIR_NO,
                                      oir.INCIDENT_DATE,
                                      e.FIRSTNAME,
                           DEPARTMENTNAME= d.NAME,
                           LOCATIONNAME=  l.NAME
                         }).ToList();
     rptr_OIR_view.DataSource = _OIR_view;
        rptr_OIR_view.DataBind();
        mpeOIR.Show();
         }
  }
```

Comment: The `ReporterCancelClick` is the handler to open the modal? How are you triggering this event?

Comment: No,its a button click,which binds the repeater and shows the model popup extender @DennisRongo